# create a big Table using HBASE client API

Tags: scala, hbase, bigtable

I am working with google cloud big table using client API in scala, 
I am trying to create a table with a single  column family but I am getting errors

Below is the code I wrote :

```
`object TestBigtable {


  val columnFamilyName = Bytes.toBytes("cf1")

  def createConnection(ProjectId: String, InstanceID: String): Connection = {
    BigtableConfiguration.connect(ProjectId, InstanceID)
  }

  def createTableIfNotExists(connection: Connection, name: String) = {
    val tableName = TableName.valueOf(name)
    val admin = connection.getAdmin()
      if (!admin.tableExists(tableName)) {
        val tableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor(tableName)
        tableDescriptor.addFamily(
          new HColumnDescriptor(columnFamilyName))
        admin.createTable(tableDescriptor)
      }
    }




  def runner(projectId: String,
             instanceId: String,
             tableName: String) = {
    val createTableConnection = createConnection(projectId, instanceId)
    try {
      createTableIfNotExists(createTableConnection, tableName)
    } finally {
      createTableConnection.close()
    }


  }`
```

Once I execute my jar I get the following set of errors:

```
    18/07/25 10:36:20 INFO com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession: Bigtable options: BigtableOptions{dataHost=bigtable.googleapis.com, adminHost=bigtableadmin.googleapis.com, port=443, projectId=renault-ftt, instanceId=testfordeletion, appProfileId=, userAgent=hbase-1.4.3, credentialType=DefaultCredentials, dataChannelCount=4, retryOptions=RetryOptions{retriesEnabled=true, allowRetriesWithoutTimestamp=false, statusToRetryOn=[UNAUTHENTICATED, ABORTED, DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, UNAVAILABLE], initialBackoffMillis=5, maxElapsedBackoffMillis=60000, backoffMultiplier=2.0, streamingBufferSize=60, readPartialRowTimeoutMillis=60000, maxScanTimeoutRetries=3}, bulkOptions=BulkOptions{asyncMutatorCount=2, useBulkApi=true, bulkMaxKeyCount=125, bulkMaxRequestSize=1048576, autoflushMs=0, maxInflightRpcs=40, maxMemory=97307852, enableBulkMutationThrottling=false, bulkMutationRpcTargetMs=100}, callOptionsConfig=CallOptionsConfig{useTimeout=false, shortRpcTimeoutMs=60000, longRpcTimeoutMs=600000}, usePlaintextNegotiation=false, useCachedDataPool=false}.
18/07/25 10:36:20 INFO com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.OAuthCredentialsCache: Refreshing the OAuth token
Exception in thread "grpc-default-executor-0" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.memoizedSize from class com.google.bigtable.admin.v2.ListTablesRequest
    at com.google.bigtable.admin.v2.ListTablesRequest.getSerializedSize(ListTablesRequest.java:236)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoInputStream.available(ProtoInputStream.java:108)
    at io.grpc.internal.MessageFramer.getKnownLength(MessageFramer.java:204)
    at io.grpc.internal.MessageFramer.writePayload(MessageFramer.java:136)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractStream.writeMessage(AbstractStream.java:52)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedStream$5.run(DelayedStream.java:218)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedStream.drainPendingCalls(DelayedStream.java:132)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedStream.setStream(DelayedStream.java:101)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport$PendingStream.createRealStream(DelayedClientTransport.java:361)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport$PendingStream.access$300(DelayedClientTransport.java:344)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport$5.run(DelayedClientTransport.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any one could help me with this please ?

Comment: Hi, can you list your dependencies? I'm guessing you have some mismatched library versions. If possible, please provide both: the dependencies listed in your build file and the resolved dependency graph.

Comment: You seem to be using protobuf light: `io.grpc.protobuf.lite` is in the stack.  The Cloud Bigtable client was never tested with protobuf lite. As Igor said, a dependency graph would help.  As a quick fix, you can also try the `bigtable-hbase-1.x-shaded` artifact instead of the `bigtable-hbase-1.x` artifact.

Answer (score 1):

Reposting the comment from Solomon as an answer:

> io.grpc.protobuf.lite is in the stack. The Cloud Bigtable client was
>   never tested with protobuf lite. A dependency graph would help. As a
>   quick fix, you can also try the bigtable-hbase-1.x-shaded artifact
>   instead of the bigtable-hbase-1.x artifact.

It's possible that your use of `io.grpc.protobuf.lite` is causing issues. As I understand it, `io.grpc.protobuf.lite` is mainly for use on Android clients.

Using the shaded artifact should prevent dependency conflicts at the cost of a larger JAR size and potential memory footprint. You may also want to review these similar issue reports and how they were resolved:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/_Yq0Dar_jhk
- https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2300